# Trying to figure out how to check a checksum

Tags: c#, binary, bit-manipulation, hex, checksum

I'm trying to figure out how to check a checksum. My message looks like this:

```
38 0A 01 12 78 96 FE 00 F0 FB D0 FE F6
```

F6 being the checksum. I convert the preceding 12 sets in to binary and then add them together. Then attempt a bitwise operation to apply the 2s complement. I get a value of -1562, but I can't convert it back to hex to check if the value is correct. Can someone point me in the right direction?

my code:

```
string[] hexValue = {"38", "0A", "01", "12", "78", "96", "FE", "00", "F0", "FB", "D0", "FE"};
int totalValue = 0;
foreach(string item in hexValue)
{
    totalValue += Int32.Parse(item, NumberStyles.HexNumber);
}

int bAfter2sC = ~totalValue + 1;
Console.Write("answer :" + bAfter2sC + "\n");
```

Comment: I don't think your checksum algorithm is correct. Are you sure you're supposed to add them up?

Comment: Is GetHashCode() http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx not ok? The checksum is whatever you say it is, so this algorithm is correct. You can tell if its working if you pass in the same set of hex values (in the same order - its not the same object if the bytes are out of order).

Comment: The single-byte sum is 0x1A, which is negated to 0xE5. Adding one yields 0xE6, not 0xF6.

Comment: @Stephen, yes got the same as you, must be something wrong with the algorithm

Answer (score 2):

Coverting to hex is available using `ToString`: `bAfter2sC.ToString("X8")`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what algorithm you are using (-1562 requires 3 bytes, not two), but how about using a standard check digit algorithm, like mod 11, also known as ISDN 10 as documented [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Check_digit): "it can be validated very simply by adding all the products together then dividing by 11."